# Replacing all uses of @[word] to link to twitter account in String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, tags

I'm trying to replace all uses of @[Insert_handle_here] to a link to the respective twitter account.

This is my current code.

```
function replaceAts(){
    for (var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        list[i].text=list[i].text.replace(/@(\w+)/g, '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">%$1</a>')
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure how it works, as I pretty much directly coped from another Stack Overflow post, but its showing up really weird on the actual web page.

For example, the text from my friends account

```
If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome @WillThaRapper
```

Shows up as 
`If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome &lt;a href&#x3D;&quot;https:&#x2F;&#x2F;twitter.com&#x2F;WillThaRapper&quot; target&#x3D;&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;%WillThaRapper&lt;&#x2F;a&gt;`

Which is not ideal.

Any advice?

Comment: Sounds like you need to assign *HTML*, not text

Comment: Where are you getting the `template` from? Is it something you control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use the `RegExp` positive lookbehind expression, or a simple function returning our desired output — which is actually more customizable.

```js
var list = [
  'If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome @WillThaRapper.',
  'Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, it can achieve @NapoleonHill.',
  'Here is @my_id and please give me @yours.'
];

function replaceAts() {
  var replacer = function(match) {
    var id = match.substr(1);

    return `<a href="https://twitter.com/${id}" target="_blank">${id}</a>`;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = list[i].replace(/@\w+/g, replacer);
  }
}

replaceAts();

console.log(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**P.S.** Let me know if you need the ES6 version of a solution as we might be able to reduce the size of those, *significantly* — or at least improve readability.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm having a little bit of difficulty using this for my implementation however. Is there any way to change your code so that instead of appending to a div element, it would instead iterate over and change the text itself in **list**? Sorry, my understanding of Jquery isn't that great.

Comment: @C.Fior There sure is a way, let me cook something for you.

Comment: @C.Fior Updated. That should do it. If you need the `RegExp` to search and replace with insensitive case, add an `i` flag on the pattern, like `/@\w+/ig`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Really need more info, but is this what you are looking for?

```js
// List of twitter tags
let list = ["@someone", "@anotherperson", "@thisperson"];

const displayAccounts = (arr) => {
  let target = document.querySelector('ul');
  arr.forEach(twit => {
    let html = `<a href="https://twitter.com/${twit}" target="_blank">${twit}</a>`;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = html;
    target.appendChild(li);
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  displayAccounts(list);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about the code inside of the replace function, but I'm not sure how you got a result at all since the function doesn't take any arguments and doesn't return anything?

Try doing this:

```
function replaceAts(tweet) {
    var newTweet = tweet.replace('@word', '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">%$1</a>')
}
return newTweet;
}

var test = 'If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome @WillThaRapper'

console.log(replaceAts(test)); //prints 'If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome <a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">%$1</a>'
```